# DropdownList: SelectIndex = 0 based upon a user clearing a text box/the text changing. Javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, attributes, drop-down-menu

I have a scenario whereby I have a textbox with an autocomplete extender attached and two drop down lists; this enables a user to search for product info.

Ideally I'd like to create something that effectivley, 'resets' the drop downs so that when a user clicks on the textbox (maybe I'll do it 'onenter'/'ondelete' if there is such a thing).

I've had a look at .Attributes.Add but cannae figure it out.

How do you include asp.net controls within this scenario so I could have something along the lines of:

```
tbxAutoComplete.Attributes.Add("OnClick", ddlLevelAuto.SelectedIndex = 0, ddlItemCategory.SelectedIndex = 0,);
```

I obviously know this doesn't work as I'm whilst banging my head on my desk :  )

Any help, gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use server-side code to reset; you need client-side JavaScript code to do this.  You can reset a drop down by setting

```
ddl.selectedIndex = 0;
```

in javascript, when the textbox fires its focus client-side event.

HTH.